# Oncoprintjs to draw an oncoprint

Tags: javascript

```
var track_params = {
  rule_set_params: {
    type: 'gradient',
    // legend_label: 'Heatmap',
    value_key: 'vaf',
    value_range: [-255, 255],
    colors: [
      [255, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 255, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 255, 1]
    ],
    // value_stop_points: [-255, 0, 255],
    null_color: 'rgba(224,224,224,0)',
  },
```

I don't know how to set the legend color to non-linear when drawing an *oncoprint* diagram, because it doesn't have a temporary official document, and I don't understand React at the moment. Reading the source code is extremely difficult.